# Shadowing real DNS names with a Kubernetes Service - for running a local subset for development

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to set up a Kubernetes cluster containing a subset of our CI environment. Specifically I'm trying to run some combination of:

- Database
- BL
- Staff UI
- Staff UI Aggregator (There are a number of Staff UI Services for different components, and this pulls them together)
- Config UI
- Config UI Aggregator (There are a number of Config UI Services for different components, and this pulls them together)

What I'm wanting to achieve is:

- If the BL service is running, Staff UI and Config UI talk to it
- If the BL service is not running, Staff UI and Config UI talk to the version in our CI environment.

What I can't do is change the DNS names that Staff UI and Config UI use to resolve the BL - and that DNS name is fully qualified.

So, what I'm wanting to do is:

- If BL is running, then the Kubernetes DNS resolves "bl.dev.company.com" to the BL Service
- If BL is not running then the Kubernetes DNS doesn't resolve "bl.dev.company.com" and it goes to the CI environment version instead.

So far, I've failed to get *either* of those steps to work :(

I'm not listing the things I've tried deliberately because there's a fair chance I've tried the correct solution, not fully understood it, done it badly and thus it's not worked.

This is using Kubernetes 1.10.3, running as part of "Docker for Desktop Edge Channel" on macOS.

I *can* get this to work using docker-compose, via `links`, but it's not as flexible. Additionally the longer term goal is to move the CI environment to a Kubernetes cluster of its own, so this would be a step towards that.

Comment: Can you control the single DNS name?  If so, an ExternalName Service essentially provides a DNS alias and you could set this to point to one place or the other, and you could make the DNS name be something like `bl-dev.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We've currently got a home grown service discovery system that I'm going to be using, so the DNS names need to match what are stored in this.

Comment: Is the "version in our CI environment" also deployed in the same Kubernetes cluster with BL and StaffUI/ConfigUI?

Comment: It's not, no. One of the longer term goals is a migration to Kube - right now it's all just VMware VMs. Additionally the Kube cluster I'm doing right here is on my laptop - so I can make changes to one service that's then used by others locally.

Answer (score 0):

You could [add host records](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) to the StaffUI/ConfigUI pods `/etc/hosts` with the DNS name you need and the `ClusterIP` of the intermediate Kubernetes Service.

Then you can update the service configuration during the BL deployment by changing the Service selector or setting ExternalName/externalIP.